# Accessing one value from MySQL using pymysql in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am trying to fetch one value from a database using `pymysql`. My current solution is 3 lines of code. Is this the best way to handle this?

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='')
conn.autocommit(True)
cur = conn.cursor()

memory = '100'

# I want to access one item from mySQL
cur.execute("""SELECT id FROM scada.sensors WHERE memory='{}'""".format(memory))
for x in cur.fetchall(): # only runs once
   sensor_id=x[0]
```

Do I need this for loop to access  the contents of `cur.fetchall()`?

I am using Python 3.2.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are only interested in one value (or the first value), you can just use the `fetchone` method in place of `fetchall`. Here's an example from the [docs for MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples) (pymysql says it copies the entire MySQLdb API).